# Eclipse: does not show Android Icons in current ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the current ADT from google (Eclipse Juno + plugins version 23 for Android L), 32 bit.
Windows 7 professional German.
Everything went smooth except that Eclipse does not show the Android icons for SDK Manager and AVD Manager. What is wrong?

Comment: Which Perspective do you have open? Be sure it is the Java one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this an answer, be sure you open the Java Perspective in Eclipse in order to see the SDK Manager and AVD Manager buttons on the toolbar.